# Want to recode a set of numbers related to months, grouping them together

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to figure out a way to recode the numbers 1 through 12 (representing months) in Excel. I could just do a bunch of nested IF's, but was trying to figure out a more elegant way to do it. I'd like to recode them like this:

```
 1 -->  1
 2 -->  2
 3 -->  3
 4 -->  4
 5 -->  5
 6 -->  6
 7 -->  6 (or 11)
 8 -->  6 (or 11)
 9 -->  6 (or 11)
10 --> 11
11 --> 11
12 --> 12
```

Basically, I want to treat October (10) as November (11), and then I can treat July-September (7-9) as either June or November (doesn't matter for my purposes). I tried doing it with a few nest MINs and MAXs, but couldn't get it to work.

Any thoughts or insight are appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CHOOSE():

```
=CHOOSE(A1,1,2,3,4,5,6,6,6,6,11,11,12)
```

[image]